# For each group apply a function and return an object of different dimension in R

Tags: r, tapply

I am using R. I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
a <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
b <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60)
y <- c(2000, 2000, 2001,2001,2002, 2002)
c <- cbind(b,a,y)
colnames(c) <- c("b", "a", "y")
```

All I want to do, is to apply the `sum` function to a group of `a` and `y`. The output may have different `dim` compared to the input.

I would expect the following result:

```
aa <- c(1,1,2,2)
yy <- c(2000,2001,2001,2002)
bb <- c(30,30,40,110)
result <- cbind(bb,aa,yy)
```

I tried the following but with little success:

```
as_tibble(c) %>% group_by(a, y) %>% mutate(tapply(, 2, FUN = sum(b)))
```

Any hint also outside `dplyr`?. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the following:

```
library(dplyr)

c %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  group_by(y, a) %>%
  summarise_all(~sum(.))
```

You can achieve the same result with base R:

`aggregate(b ~ y + a, data = as.data.frame(c), sum)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(c)[, lapply(.SD, sum), .(y, a)]
```